# How to know when my WKWebview derived subview is loaded in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, subview

I have a view, which loads a subview after certain actions have happened, within the viewDidLoad() method:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //OTHER STUFF...
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.userContentController = contentController
        self.myWebView = WKWebView(
            frame: self.containerView.bounds,
            configuration: config
        )
        self.myWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.myWebView)
    }
```

I need to do some checks once the web view has loaded. How can I do something like:

```
webSubviewDidLoad() {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: The WKWebView has a delegate that you can use to determine when the webview has loaded content, I think it's called ```didFinishNavigation```, you can check the documentation for that.

Comment: Not really sure what do you mean by web view has loaded, you mean web view is done with loading its content or if its simply moved to superview

Comment: @SandeepBhandari loaded content

Comment: @wayneio : I think you already have a answer from cristallo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a specific delegate didFinishNavigation

[didFinishNavigation documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview?language=objc)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(webView)

        /* add layout constraints that make the webview fitting in your view */

        if let url = URL(string: "https://google.com") {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
    }

}

  extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Finished navigating to url \(webView.url)")
    }

}
```

or you can check the estimatedProgress property for the progress

[estimatedProgress documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415007-estimatedprogress?language=objc)

Comment: cristallo, can we also use the webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView: WKWebView) method? What is difference between the two methods?

Comment: both webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate and didFinishNavigation are currently fired at the end. The apple documentation is not so clear about the differences. My guess is that for complex web pages that needs a lot of processing the webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate could be a better option. It depends by your context. NOTE: I am not sure if the isLoading property is related to the first one or to the second one since in my test app all happen at the same time. Probably because my test web page is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Add an observer to be notified when your web view finishes loading like below. This code should be placed within viewDidLoad method of your view controller class.

```
myWebView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
```

Step 2. Implement the observeValue(forKeyPath:) method in your view controller, doing whatever actions you need to do like below.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "isLoading" && !myWebView.isLoading {
        // Do your needed action here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own WebView:

```js
import WebKit

protocol WebViewDelegate {
    func didLayoutSubviews()
}

class WebView : WKWebView {
    
    weak var delegate: WebViewDelegate?
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.delegate?.didLayoutSubviews()
    }
}
```